# function to check string list in order give negative result

Tags: java

I have the below function to check if it is in order

```
 public boolean order(List<String> value) {
            List<String> tmp = value;
            Collections.sort(tmp);
            return tmp.equals(value);
        }
```

Test:

```
assertTrue(route.order(Arrays.asList("a", "s", "d")));
assertFalse(route.order(Arrays.asList("a", "k", "c")));
```

but fail at 2nd test, why is it not false?

Comment: "A", "C", "D" is already ordered, if you order it again, it will still be "A", "C", "D", so why would you expect it to be false?

Comment: @fantaghirocco no, not a duplicate of that one - in this case here, even the references are equal

Answer (score 4):

Here in below line:

```
List<String> tmp = value;
```

You are just copying reference of `value` list argument in `tmp` list and hence you are sorting on `tmp` and indirectly `value` list which is one and the same.

To solve the problem change the assignment of `tmp` variable to:

```
List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean order(List<String> value) {
   List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(value);
   Collections.sort(tmp);
   return tmp.equals(value);
 }
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed and why it solves the problem?

Comment: @JJJ i have given complete program with working conditon by solving his issue.

Comment: Yes, I can see that you have code in the answer. Answers are expected to also explain what the problem was and why the code solves the problem.

Comment: @JJJ I understand that sir, but explanation is already given in another answer, so i given whole program logic with working condition.

Comment: @JJJ if you need explanation to this i can add that also.

Comment: Thanks, that would be great.

Answer (score -2):

Your asserts are negative to each other.
Both arrays are sorted. Maybe you wanted ("A", "C", "B").

Also, as the fellows said before, your sort is on the original list, you have to copy it first and then to sort.

Comment: If you wanted ("A", "C", "B"), then you should not sort the Lists, or maybe use a Comparator other than the NaturalOrder to sort them

Comment: @TGH, you are right. But the real problem is not here, what you point was just a writing mistake in OP question.